# java spring jwt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Сделал регистрацию и авторизацию с JWT. Но при обращении к любому маппингу получаю ошибку: Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/' (previous null). Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.

Конфигурация spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private UserService userService;
    private TokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTokenFilter(TokenFilter tokenFilter) {
        this.tokenFilter = tokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationManagerBuilder configureAuthenticationManagerBuilder(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(request ->
                                new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()))
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/secured/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Я новичок и относительно недавно начал изучать Spring, но смею предположить что ошибка в том что Вы сначала защищаете свои маппинги `/secured/**` и даете к ним доступ только полностью авторизованным юзерам, но в следующей строке Вы указываете что к любому из ваших маппингов доступ открыт всем.

Comment: Почитал сейчас, оказывается я был не прав, извините, ваше предупреждение связано с обновлением Spring и сопоставлением запросов, команда Spring Framework пока не предоставила комплексного решения, можно лишь отключить данное предупреждение. Подробнее можете ознакомиться: [HandlerMappingIntrospector](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31588)